# Binding to base class property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have classes like this:

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<A> Children { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
}
public class C : A
{
    public ObservableCollection<A> Children2 { get { return Children; } }
}
```

And i'm trying to bind them using `HierarchicalDataTemplate` like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:B} ItemSource="{Binding Children}">
    <TextBlock Text="foo"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:C} ItemSource="{Binding Children2}">
    <TextBlock Text="bar"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Which results in B beeing not expandable (as if nothing was bound) while C works just fine.
How do I bind to base class property without need to expose it again in derived class?

Comment: the binding to the base should work fine. I have never had that problem - ever. So you gotta look somewhere else for the issue. Somehow, the binding path is not resolving, I cannot tell from this sample why..